# Entity Framework with EntityDataSource throws MetadataException when installed on Windows 2008 server

Tags: entity-framework, entitydatasource

I have a problem with installing a Web Application on a server which is using an EntityDataSource and the .NET Framework June CTP.
I posted the question on the MSDN Forums but still have no answer:
[EF with POCO templates and DbContext throws MetadataException when installed on server](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/55d23154-eb63-428c-9767-47fc3cb43f61)

The following Exception is throwed when installing the application on a windows 2008 server with IIS 7 and when using an EntityDataSource in combination with the June CTP Framework which we need for using POCO and the DbContext.

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.Data.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>   Library.csdl(2,9) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information
>   for the attribute 'Namespace'. Library.csdl(2,34) : warning 0005:
>   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Alias'.
>   Library.csdl(2,2) : error 0010: The element Schema in namespace
>   `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm` was unexpected for the
>   root element. The expected Schema in one of the following namespaces:
>   `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm`,
>   `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm`,
>   `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm`. at
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1
>   xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption
>   dataModelOption, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, ItemCollection
>   itemCollection, Boolean throwOnError)

When we create a test project without the June CTP Framework it is working. When we do not use the EntityDataSource with the June CTP Framework it works too. We developed some months with this EntityDataSource so it's not easy to change the code and use something else.

Comment: June CTP is dead. Don't use it. All features from June CTP are now part of .NET 4.5 Beta and Entity Framework 5.0 Beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server appears to have .NET 3.5 SP 1, and the CTP requires .NET 4. The schemata in the error message (2006-8) are EF 10 2009/11/edm are EF 4.

Comment: Problem solved! Reinstalling the June CTP solved the problem. I think the EFTools.msi was not correct installed or not installed at all. Thanks!

Comment: Follow Ladislav's comment. There is no reason to use the June CTP. .NET Framework 4.5 Beta contains everything what was included in the CTP plus quite a few bug fixes - especially for new features. In addition .NET Framework 4.5 has a "go-live" release as opposed to the June CTP whose license does not allow you to use the CTP in the production environment. Also .NET Framework 4.5 is a fully supported release.

Comment: I will try to uninstall the June CTP and install and use the 4.5 version. For our demo the June CTP is working, for the release I will use framework 4.5. Thanks for the explanations.